# How to make details of a graph sorted

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a directory that has 6 folders within. I am plotting folders automatically but when I see the result, it is a bit weird. While the folders are sorted in the computer, the plot is not ordered. For example, I want to have the result of C_r 0.05 before C_r 0.1 and so on. I have plotted using my folder path and I do not know how to make an example of this since I am plotting from my computer but I will put the graph that I have obtained and the code which plots the graph.

```
import os
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
#matplotlib qt

root = r'/home/hossein/Desktop/Out/INTERSECTION/BETA 15'
xx=[]
percentage=[]
labels = []
gg=[]
my_list = os.listdir(root)
my_list =  [file for file in my_list if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, file))]
percetanges = []
for directory in my_list:

    CASES = [file for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, directory)) if file.startswith('config')]

    if len(CASES)==0:
        continue
    CASES.sort()

    #print(CASES)


    percentage=[]


    for filename in CASES:
       # print(filename)

        with open(os.path.join(root, directory,filename), "r") as file: 


        #files[filename] = file.read()
            lines = file.readlines()
            x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
            y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]

            #_new = np.array(y)

            g = np.linspace(min(y),max(y),100)

            h = min(y)*0.9
            t = max(y)*0.9

            xx=[]

            for i in range(1,len(x)):

                if (y[i] < h or y[i] > t):
                    xx.append(x[i])

            percent = len(xx)/len(y)

        percentage.append(percent)
    labels.append(directory)
    labels=sorted(labels)
    percetanges.append(percentage)
    percetanges=sorted(percetanges)

for i, x in enumerate(percetanges):
    plt.boxplot(x,positions=[i],whis=0.001)

plt.xticks(np.arange(len(labels)),labels)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easy. it just needed to sort your directory before plotting. I mean when you want to read just by `my_list.sort()` . then you will find the right plot in order[image]